# Detect Button Press in Tab Page

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, event-handling

I am using the WinAPI to create a GUI utility. I have two Tabs and each tab has some buttons. I am creating the buttons with this function:

```
CreateWindowEx(NULL,"button", "Clear", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
          150, 175, 100, 25, tab_window_2, (HMENU) CLEAR_DATA, instance_handle, NULL);
```

In the Windows proc function, I don't know how to detect when the above button is pressed. I also tried handling `CLEAR_DATA` in the `WM_COMMAND` switch construct, as follows.

```
switch ( message ) {  
    case WM_COMMAND:{
        switch(LOWORD(wparam)) {

            case CLEAR_DATA : break
    }
}
```

How can I detect and handle those buttons being pressed?

I am creating the tab_window_2 tab as follows :

```
class frame_window {  
    private:
        LPCSTR window_class_name;  
        HINSTANCE instance_handle;  
        HCURSOR cursor_arrow;  
        HWND window_handle;
        HWND tab_handle;
        HWND tab_window_1;
        HWND tab_window_2;
        HWND current_tab_window;
        RECT client_rectangle;   
    public:
        frame_window(LPCSTR window_class_identity) : window_class_name(window_class_identity) {  
            INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX common_controls; 
            common_controls.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX); 
            common_controls.dwICC = ICC_BAR_CLASSES; 
            InitCommonControlsEx(&common_controls); 
            int screen_width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN);  
            int screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN);  
            instance_handle = GetModuleHandle(NULL);  

            WNDCLASS window_class = { CS_OWNDC, main_window_proc, 0, 0,    
                                      instance_handle, NULL,    
                                      NULL, NULL, NULL,    
                                      window_class_name };   

            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
            // Create a standard frame window   
            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   

            RegisterClass(&window_class);   
            window_handle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,    
                                           window_class_name,    
                                           "IR Remote and Barcode Demo",   
                                           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | 
                                           WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,   
                                           100, 100, screen_width-1600,    
                                           screen_height-490, NULL, NULL,   
                                           instance_handle, NULL);


           //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            // Get the size of the client rectangle for the window we have just created
            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            RECT client_rect; 
            GetClientRect(window_handle, &client_rect); 

            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            // Create the tab control window.
            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

            tab_handle = CreateWindowEx(NULL, WC_TABCONTROL, NULL,
                                        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                        10, 10, client_rect.right-client_rect.left-20,
                                        client_rect.bottom-client_rect.top-10,
                                        window_handle, NULL, 
                                        instance_handle, NULL);

            // Create three tabs.
            TCITEM tab_info;
            memset(&tab_info, 0, sizeof(tab_info));
            tab_info.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
            tab_info.pszText = "tab#1";
            tab_info.cchTextMax = 5;
            SendMessage(tab_handle, TCM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tab_info);
            tab_info.pszText = "tab#2";
            SendMessage(tab_handle, TCM_INSERTITEM, 1, (LPARAM)&tab_info);

            RECT tab_rectangle;
            GetClientRect(tab_handle, &tab_rectangle);
            SendMessage(tab_handle, TCM_ADJUSTRECT, FALSE, (LPARAM)&tab_rectangle);

            // Create the tab view windows
            tab_window_1 = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "STATIC", "  ",
                                          WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE|SS_OWNERDRAW,
                                          tab_rectangle.left+10, tab_rectangle.top+10, 
                                          tab_rectangle.right-tab_rectangle.left,
                                          tab_rectangle.bottom -tab_rectangle.top,
                                          tab_handle, (HMENU)1, 
                                          instance_handle, NULL);

            SetParent(tab_window_1, window_handle);
            current_tab_window = tab_window_1;
            tab_window_2 = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "STATIC", " ",
                                          WS_CHILD|SS_OWNERDRAW,
                                          tab_rectangle.left+10, tab_rectangle.top+10, 
                                          tab_rectangle.right-tab_rectangle.left,
                                          tab_rectangle.bottom -tab_rectangle.top,
                                          tab_handle, (HMENU)2, 
                                          instance_handle, NULL);


          CreateWindowEx(NULL,"button", "Clear", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
              150, 175, 100, 25, tab_window_2, (HMENU) CLEAR_DATA, instance_handle, NULL);

            SetParent(tab_window_2, window_handle);

            SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW)); 
            SetWindowLongPtr(window_handle, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG)this);  
            ShowWindow(window_handle, SW_SHOW);   
            UpdateWindow(window_handle); 
        }  
        ~frame_window() {  
            UnregisterClass(window_class_name, instance_handle);   
        }  

//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
// Windows main entry point   
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE instance_handle, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, INT) {  
    frame_window main_window("my base window");  
    main_window.run();  
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WM_COMMAND` for handling the events from a Push Button must be in the Window Procedure of it's parent. Your code show `tab_window_2` as the parent for the `CLEAR_DATA` button.

Move the `WM_COMMAND` code in the right Window Proc (or Dialog Proc).

EDIT: I think you didn't understand how the Tab Control works.
If you want each Tab View to contain more than a dummy static control, you should use modeless and borderless DialogBox, children of the Tab Control, and show/hide them accordingly to the `TCN_SELCHANGE` notification.

If you don't realy need the Dialog Box functionalities, you could create regular child windows (with RegisterClass/CreateWindow) and then add your controls as child windows.

In either case, the show/hide code must react to `TCN_SELCHANGE`.

With regular child windows or with Dialog Box the net effect is the same: you will have a Window Procedure, or a Dialog Procadure, in which `WM_COMMAND` will deal with user actions.

Don't play with `SetParent`. But, if you absolutly **want** it, then use:

```
HWND hWndPushClear = CreateWindowEx(NULL,"button", "Clear", [...]
SetParent( hWndPushClear, window_handle );
```

You may have **weird** Paint/Focus problems, however.

EDIT: Unfortunately, it seems that there is no good Tab Control tutorial in line.
I recommend updating your actual source code. As a starting point, do the following:

1. Replace `CreateWindowEx` by [CreateDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `tab_window_1` end `tab_window_2` (only one Dialog must be visible)
2. Suppress all `SetParent` calls

Comment: `tab_window_2` is the tab handler of tab2 page in a tab controller and using `setParent()` function I have made the main window handler as the parent. Can you suggest me how I can add a window proc to the `tab_window_2` handler.

Comment: @kumar Update your question with code showing how you create the tab_window_2 window.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I think I need to use the TCN_SELCHNAGE notification . Do you have any tutorial for the tab controller, I didn't get proper tutorial on the net other than mdn explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CreateWindowEx()` and `WM_COMMAND` code are seems correct. 
So,

1. Check return value of `CreateWindowEx()` whether is `NULL`. `NULL` means which is failed to create control.
2. Check `HWND` of parent is valid. In your code, it is `tab_window_2`.

Also, if you do not want to any `WS_EX_XXX` style, you can just use `CreateWindow()`.

This code is just sample.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,UINT iMessage,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(iMessage) {
case WM_CREATE:
    CreateWindow("button","Clear",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
        20,20,100,25,hWnd,(HMENU)0,g_hInst,NULL);
    return 0;
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case 0:
        MessageBox(hWnd,"Clear Button Clicked","Button",MB_OK);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
}
return(DefWindowProc(hWnd,iMessage,wParam,lParam));
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the code, I am able to make work with the single window, but in my GUI I have the tab page which has the buttons and I am looking a way to detect the button press on the tab.

Comment: Do you mean Property Sheet?